# How to keep div height fixed during changing its content?

Tags: jquery, html, css

```
<div id='wrapT'>some stuff here</div>
<div id='btnsT'>
<img id='prev' src='btns/prev_01.png' alt='prev'>
<img id='next' src='btns/next_01.png' alt='next'>
</div>
```

js

```
    $('#btnsT #next').click(function(){
    var a = $('#divsT > div').eq(xdiv).html();
    $('#wrapT').html(a);
});
```

`#wrapT` changes its content correctly, but it firstly changes its `height` to `0` for a few seconds, then come back to original height.

How to keep the height fixed during this process?

IMPORTANT: both the old and the new content is 450px in height.

I tried in css:

```
#wrapT{
    height:450px;
}
```

But in this case there is a problem during re-sizing the window - it stays always 450px.

also tried to add in btn click event:

```
var x = $('#wrapT').height();
$('#wrapT').css('height', x + 'px');
$('#wrapT').html(a);
$("#wrapT").css('height', 'auto');
```

witout success. `#wrapT` keeps to change its height.

Comment: Do you want the height to change as the screen resizes? If so you are going to want to set the height to a percentage rather than pixels. You can use the min-height property if you don't want it to go below a certain height, too.

Comment: You can try `overflow:hidden;`.

Comment: @bsayegh, but I don't know how much percents, because the main part of content is an image whose width is given in pixels.

Comment: @BindiyaPatoliya, `overflow` does not have any link with the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done something similar before. What you can do is load the next item **behind** the current one with `visibility:hidden;` and possibly a lesser z-index. This means the shape of wrapT will stay.

You can then do something like:

```
$('#OldItem').fadeOut(400, function() {
   $(this).remove();
});
$('#NewItem').fadeIn(400)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `min-height max-height min-width max-width` for your element.

Comment: min height prevents the div's responsive feauture

Comment: You can then set height and max-height same. If you know the dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

To give it a fixed position you basically want to set the minimal and maximal height both to the desired height.

```
#wrapT{
    min-height:450px;
    max-height:450px;
    height:450px;
    width:300px;
}
```

It changes to 0px because it takes some time to retrieve the data.

You could also use websockets so that it wait with updating whenever the data is there, but ofcourse this is not practical (in your case).

Comment: Daan, giving fixed height responsive feature is off.

Comment: I answered your question: `How to keep div height fixed during changing its content?`. You're not talking about any responsive future.

Comment: To Quote: _But in this case there is a problem during re-sizing the window - it stays always 450px._ 
I read that as "450px all the time is bad"...